# Image upload in a clustered tomcat, database or file system

Tags: java, tomcat

I had a requirement for uploading Images Java web project with clustered tomcats.
The issue I'm facing is weather to upload images on the file system or the database.
Since with file system there is an issue with integrity(inconsistent images across the clustered nodes) but performance is faster.

Had got the solution of syncing files between two node through a hybrid approach.
Did instantaneous sync between each node by making a Rest post of the file by converting it to a base 64 string and posting as XML, to the other nodes in cluster in a separate thread.
As a consequence of this many scenarios arose when the design would fail. (One of them being that one node is down while upload happens on the other node.). Then came up with the solution of keep DB as a Master copy for sync on server start-up and use secondary storage on other times.

Still the solution seemed too complex so we resorted to a ***shared mounted drive***, as suggested by [**Andrey Chaschev**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1851024/andrey-chaschev) and [**venergiac**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1645339/venergiac). It worked like a charm. guess the only plus point of this RnD was I got pretty familiar with what Rest can and can't do and Jgroups for messaging between cluster aware tomcats.

Comment: Have you considered uploading the image to Amazon's [Simple Storage Service (S3)](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A distributed file system might be what you need. In one of my previous projects I used [GlusterFS](http://www.gluster.org/community/documentation/index.php/QuickStart) and the experience was quite smooth - the DFS is seen as a folder which is shared between hosts to which any of the hosts may write or read. It promises to be fault tolerant. Googling for a modern solution gives out [XtreemFS](http://www.xtreemfs.org/).

From what I read about DFS vs FS vs NFS, DFS are much faster and easier to configure than NFS and are a bit slower than direct file copying via network.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,

I save the files on the database (Oracle);

however, you could use a shared directory between the nodes of the cluster (NFS or CIFS).